# Monstache creating multople indices for single mongo collection in Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, monstache

On running monstache server, it is creating index `cdp.master-users` in elasticsearch as expected. When I stop the monstache server and start back after sometime, it is creating a new index `65167c8a25634f0d84692fc5_cdp.master-users` in elasticsearch.

When this resume happens, all the lost operations from the last timestamp are getting synced to `65167c8a25634f0d84692fc5_cdp.master-users` while all the new operations are getting synced to `cdp.master-users` index.

Is this an expected behavior because I am unable to find anything on this in the documentation. I want monstache to use same index when resumed instead of creating a new one.

I am using latest monstache version with AWS Elasticsearch 7.10 and Mongo db Atlas 6.0.10.

I have following monstache config:

```
mongo-url = 

elasticsearch-urls = [""]

change-stream-namespaces = ["cdp.master-users"]

elasticsearch-user = 
elasticsearch-password = 
resume= true
verbose = true
exit-after-direct-reads = false


[[script]]
script = """
module.exports = function(doc) {
    if (doc.id && doc.id.$oid) {
      doc._id = doc.id.$oid;
    }
  
    if (doc.name && doc.name.updatedAt && doc.name.updatedAt.$date) {
      doc.name.updatedAt = new Date(doc.name.updatedAt.$date.$numberLong);
    }

    if (doc.updatedAt && doc.updatedAt.$date) {
        doc.updatedAt = new Date(doc.updatedAt.$date.$numberLong);
      }

    if (doc.createdAt && doc.createdAt.$date) {
        doc.createdAt = new Date(doc.createdAt.$date.$numberLong);
      }
    return doc;
  };
  """
```